# Database models site

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

There was a site which had a lot of database entity relation diagrams models, I helped a lot as a guide, because some of the implementations proposed where really good.

Does anyone knows about a site like that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Database Answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)?